# Exporting & Using custom control in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I have built a custom control, following tutorials online (which are in abundance) and some of my own knowledge.
the tutorials, by the way, showed nothing about compiling and using the control in another project.

I am relatively new to iOS development, and would like to know how to export the custom control so it can be used in another app (like an sdk).

can I do this without an Apple's ID, developer account, etc. ?
since it's only a control (is it supposed to be an ipa)? does it need a signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1) simply drag the file(s) containing your custom control class(es) into another project

2) or you can [create a framework](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios).

In the first case it will be just some text files with code and in the second case these files will be compiled into a framework, which doesn't require a signature. When you add that framework to another project and build it, the binary is linked with the framework and everything is signed automatically, so you needn't worry about that.